# I'm a Sage developer

Tags: discussion

In the interest of full disclosure, I am a Sage developer.  I'm preparing a patch that affects the Dancing Links interface in Sage.  The scores of some of my solutions past and future will be impacted by this.  For example,

`ExactCovers(...)`

instead of

`[[p[i]for i in x]for x in DLXCPP(p)]`

and

`ExactCovers(...,1)`

instead of

`sum(1 for x in DLXCPP(...))`

or

`len(list(DLXCPP(...))`

by a side-effect of the function definition

`ExactCovers(problem,count_only=False,solution_callback=True)`.

I think, as both a Sage developer and a researcher using this function, that this is the right interface for the Dancing Links algorithm.  I put the old interface in, and it's [time to fix it](http://trac.sagemath.org/ticket/11814).

Comment: Er...are you sure that you have posted to the right place? I don't see what this has to do with CodeGolf.SE.

Comment: @dmckee I'm changing Sage in a way that will improve my scores on codegolf.se.  I feel that warrants disclosure.

Comment: Sounds good to me. I mean, Sage isn't a "designed for golfing" language, so if improvements to the language makes existing golf solutions shorter, I'd say that's a good thing.